# Python Rock,Paper,Scissors User Input in a while loop

Tags: while-loop, user-input, python-3.9

I am making a simple rock paper scissors terminal program in python and I want the player to input their name only once throughout the game.

```
from random import random, randint
import random

running = True
global p_wins,p_losses,p_draws,c_wins,c_losses,c_draws
p_wins = 0
p_losses = 0
p_draws = 0
c_wins = 0
c_losses = 0
c_draws = 0

while running == True:
    print("=====Rock Paper Scissors: The Python Game=====")
    print("\n")
#Point System
    def Score():

        print("====Player's Score====")
        print(f"Wins:{p_wins}")
        print(f"Losses:{p_losses}")
        print(f"Draws:{p_draws}")

        print("====CPU's Score====")
        print(f"Wins:{c_wins}")
        print(f"Losses:{c_losses}")
        print(f"Draws:{c_draws}")

    name = input("Player please enter you name:\n")
    print("\n")

    if name == str(name):
        pass


    if len(name) > 12:
        print("Player's name is TOO long")
        break

    myItem = input("Enter Either Rock Paper or Scissors:\n")


    if myItem not in ("Rock","Paper","Scissors"):
       print("Are you Ok!! I said enter rock paper or scissors")
       print("GAME OVER!!!!!!")
       break
    

#Computer's Choices
    computerItem = random.randint(1,3)
    if computerItem == 1:
        computerItem = "Rock"
        print(f"Computer chooses {computerItem}...")
    if computerItem == 2:
        computerItem = "Paper"
        print(f"Computer chooses {computerItem}...")
    if computerItem == 3:
        computerItem = "Scissors"
        print(f"Computer chooses {computerItem}...")


    if myItem == computerItem:
        print("Try Again!! You and the CPU picked the same thing")
        p_draws += 1
        c_draws += 1
        Score()
        

#How I can loose to the CPU
    if myItem == "Rock" and computerItem == "Paper":
        print("[Paper covers Rock]")
        print("CPU WINS!!!")
        p_losses += 1
        c_wins += 1
        Score()
        
    if myItem == "Paper" and computerItem == "Rock":
        print("[Paper covers Rock]")
        print(f"{name} WINS!!!")
        p_wins += 1
        c_losses += 1
        Score()

    if myItem == "Scissors" and computerItem == "Rock":
        print("[Rock Smashes Scissors]")
        print("CPU WINS!!!")
        p_losses += 1
        c_wins += 1
        Score()
        
    if myItem == "Rock" and computerItem == "Scissors":
        print("[Rock smashes Scissors]")
        print(f"{name} WINS!!!")
        p_wins += 1
        c_losses += 1
        Score()
        

    if myItem == "Paper" and computerItem == "Scissors":
        print("[Scissors cut Paper]")
        print("CPU WINS!!!")
        p_losses += 1
        c_wins += 1
        Score()
        

    if myItem == "Scissors" and computerItem == "Paper":
        print("[Scissors cut Paper]")
        print(f"{name} WINS!!!")
        p_wins += 1
        c_losses += 1
        Score()

    nextRound = 1
        

    quitGame = input("Do you want to continue playing (Y/N):\n")

    if quitGame == "N":
         break
```

Everything else is running smoothly and without issue. I want the player to input their name only at the beginning and not at the start of every round.

```
if name == str(name):
        pass
```

I have a rough idea but I don't know how to implement it. Please can anyone help?
PS - I am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

You are having the code that takes the `name` in the while loop, so the best thing to do is to take it out of the loop for it to run once. Like this

```
name = input("Player please enter your name:\n"
if len(name)>=12:
  print("Player's name is TOO long")
  break
```

and have the main loop like this

```
while running ==True and len(name)>0:
```

Comment: I don't quite follow

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).